# how to integrate Admob Interstitial with Sprite Kit ?

Tags: xcode, admob, sprite-kit

This is my First Sprite game, and for some reason the only difficult I've been run to is the admob integration.
This is my ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// showing for the first time my AdMob Interstitial
[self showAdmobFullscreen];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

SKScene *mc = [GameScene01 sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

mc.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

[skView presentScene:mc];
}
```

and this is my Admob Settings:

```
-(void)showAdmobFullscreen{
NSLog(@" showAdmoBFullScreenCalled");

//    self.interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
//    self.interstitial.delegate = self;
//    self.interstitial.adUnitID = ADMOB_FULLSCREEN_ID;
//    [self.interstitial loadRequest:[self adMobrequest]];
interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc]init];
interstitial_.delegate = self;
interstitial_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-1032576214759203/773434443";
[interstitial_ loadRequest:[self adMobrequest]];
}

   - (GADRequest *)adMobrequest {
     NSLog(@"requestHasBeenCalled");

     GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        request.testDevices = @[
                        // TODO: Add your device/simulator test identifiers here. Your device             identifier is printed to
                        // the console when the app is launched.

                        //@"9481d65c607d68c867a51229a3c61340"
                        ];
return request;
}
```

So Far So Good, The admob is fire when the game load. now I want to fire it every time when the user lose in the game.
Right now the whole game run into my Sprite files, and what I tried todo is to call the 'showAdmobFullscreen' every time there's a GameOver
So in my Sprite.m file, I have a method called GameOver, I've added those lines :

```
-(void)GameOver
{
//Trying to make Admob shows whenever User loses a game

MyMainViewController *spVc = [[MyMainViewController alloc]init];
[spVc showAdmobFullscreen];
```

I can see the logs of my Admob are being called but no ads are showing up.
any suggestion will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 MyMainViewController *spVc = [[MyMainViewController alloc]init];  
    [spVc showAdmobFullscreen];
```

Try this

```
[self showAdmobFullscreen];
```

Comment: Thats was my first attempt. the Ad is loading in one Class (ex. FirstViewController) and i'm trying to load the Ad in other class (ex. SpriteView), so I import the class of FirstViewController to the SpriteView, and I can see in the Output ( NSLogs I made ) that it is loading, but nothing is showing up.